# How to use OpenSSL as external package?

Tags: macos, openssl, cryptography, package-managers

I am quite new to using external packages in C++. I need to use OpenSSL to compute some SHA-1 values inside a program I am writing. I am working on a Mac and need the sources from my program to be shareable to someone having a different configuration.

I would like to know the best practice on how to use OpenSSL to my project. Should I "copy" the whole library in my projects folder? Only relevant files? If not, how should I include it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use a dependency manager like [Conan](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Apple provides an antique version of OpenSSL, but it should be usable to calculate a SHA-1 digest without the need for an updated OpenSSL. If you want to include an updated OpenSSL in your source tree, then see [What are Frameworks?](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html) in the Apple Developer docs.

Comment: To answer your original titular question of *"How do I use OpenSSL in C++"*, see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption | C++ Programs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#C.2B.2B_Programs). It offers a few hints for using OpenSSL in C++ programs. `std::unique_ptr` and a custom allocator are the only interesting things. Just about everything else is the same as in C.

Comment: Note that SHA-1 has been SHAttered.io